# when to index on multiple keys in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

say I have an Item document with :price and :qty fields. I sometimes want to find all documents matching a given :price AND :qty, and at other times it will be either :price on its own or :qty on its own.

I have already indexed the :price and :qty keys, but do I also need to create a compound index on both together or are the single key indexes enough?

Edit: I found this article on the mongodb site very useful:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ

Comment: yea, i would love to know what other ppl thinks. I have a collection where i could search against multiple "fields." Obviously _id is indexed but I have a handful of others as well.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

An index on `price` helps with queries on `price`.  An index on `qty` helps with queries on `qty`.  An index on `price` and `qty` helps with queries on `price` AND queries on `price` and `qty`.  So, it's like getting two indexes for the price of one.  It will not help for queries on `qty`, though.

You should minimize the number of indexes you have, so drop one of your single-key indexes and create a compound index starting with that key.

As a general rule, if you're doing a query on `x`, `y`, and `z`, you should have an index like `{x:1, y:1, z:1}`.  This index will make the following queries fast:

```
db.foo.find({x : ..., y : ..., z : ...})
db.foo.find({x : ..., y : ...})
db.foo.find({x : ...})
```

It will not make these queries fast:

```
db.foo.find({y : ..., z : ...})
db.foo.find({y : ...})
```

So, make sure your query has the starting key(s) of an index in it.

Comment: This has changed since 1.6+, now Mongo can use any key from a compound index: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeysIndexes

Comment: indeed, I forgot to add that.

Comment: what about a query for `db.foo.find({x : ..., z : ...})`, will it make that query fast when the middle index key is missing from the query?

Answer (score -6):

if you need  :price on its own or :qty on its own then a compound index won't work.

Comment: I have single indexes at the moment, I want to know if I also need a compound index for the query that runs on both :price and :qty

Comment: That's not true.  The compound index :price+:qty will help for :price on its own since :price is first in the compound index.